# Время срабатывания таймера

Tags: javascript

```
 1.
 function fn(){
            alert(new Date().getTime()-last);
            }
        var last=new Date().getTime();
        setTimeout(fn,200)// FF ,IE8,  Сhrome  около 200

   2. 
    function fn(){
            alert(new Date().getTime()-last);
            }
        var last=new Date().getTime();
        setTimeout(fn,200);//ie8 1125 FF 208 Chrome 203
        for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            var j=j+1;
            }
```

Как написано в одной книге ,через 200мс функция в интервале будет добавлена в очередь , а не сработает.Это задание будет ожидать очереди выполнения ,пока не будут выполнены все функции находящиеся в этой очереди до этого.
Так вот меня интересует это что IE8 ждет пока не выполнится цикл а потом только запускаетсяба остальные не ждут выполнения цикла?

Comment: Я думаю дело всё же тут в том что таймер не точный. по моему значение "около 200" и 208 и 203 - являются одним и тем же значением. Вы бы для тестов хотя бы взяли 2 секунды, а сравнивать разность в 5 микро секунд... браузерных микро секунд....

Comment: Дело в IE8.Это я понял что таймер может отличается на несколько мс

Comment: Да, похоже что он что то делает в одном потоке. если запустить вызов цикла тоже в таймаут то до 100 мс оно ведёт себя так же, после - 100мс - срабатывает как должно

Comment: спасибо вам за коментарии.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS, на уровне программиста, работает в одном потоке, даже если вы задали точный таймер, но, в этот момент времени, у вас занят поток, таймер, естественно, выполнен не будет, вернее будет выполнен с "опозданием". Если вам интересно почему у IE настолько плохие результаты, то, если без грязных слов, реализация JS в нем - не очень.

Вообще меня удивляет то, что можно этого не знать, любая книга по JS, даже из разряда - "выучи за 2 недели" об этом упоминает.

---

Специально для неверующего тов. [[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4) 'а, открываем chrome, вставляем в консоль и выполняем:

```
console.time('timer');
setTimeout(function() {
  console.timeEnd('timer')
}, 200);
for( var i=0; i<1000000; ++i ) {
   // ....
}
// у меня 2274ms
```

смотрим, понимаем что я был прав, ставим плюсик

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь что НЕ В ИЕ8 (А даже в ИЕ9), таймер выполняется в том же потоке. Проверить просто - запускаете таймер и "вешаете" функцию. Таймер сработает. Если было бы так как Вы говорите, то он бы не сработал никогда.

Comment: Сыплю голову пеплом. в ИЕ тупо тормозной JS.

Comment: JS в IE не просто тормозной, он тупо ужасен, в прочем не только в 8ом, в 9ом и 10ом он, определенно, не дотягивает до уровня "взрослых" браузеров

Comment: В 9вятом у меня результаты данного скрипта, такой же как у хрома, правда при увеличении счётчика девятко явно тупее

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а как js строит очередь? Т.е. как он определяет что поток свободен и можно запускать следующее из очереди?

Comment: @Чад там все очень просто, на low level'e, грубо говоря, тупо работает вечный цикл (e.g. `while(true)`), по сути он ничего не определяет, просто делает то, что вы ему говорите делать.

Т.е., по сути, setTimeout, в данном случае, работае примерно так:

     doForLoop();
     checkTimeouts();

Т.е. пока doForLoop() не будет выполнен, естественно, timeout тоже выполнен не будет.

Естественно это упрощенно, но суть остается таже

Comment: Вообще меня удивляет то, что в ответе 3 раза написано одно и тоже

Comment: @Spectre - злой вы :( Хотя я согласен, странно смотрится, видимо при редактировании ошибся. Мораль сей басни такова - копипаст зло

Answer (score 1):

Да видимо надо смотреть в сторону [WebWorker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker). Кроме IE его уже все держат. Спасибо [@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope), подоткрыл глаза.